# If array equal array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Is possible to make `if($array1[0]=>somevalue == $array2[0]=>somevalue){echo true;}else{echo false;}`? because I cant make it work, can you help me please,

Example:
    $array1([0] => 'Joe', [2] => 'Pairs');
    $array2([0] => 'info' => array([0] => 'joe'));

```
foreach($array2->info as $info){
    foreach($array1 as $name){
        if($name == $info[0]){
             echo 'true';
           }
           else{
             echo 'false';
           }
      }
  }
```

And this is the real code,

The arrays:

```
 Array
(
[0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [companyLocationInfo] => Array
            (
                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [companyName] => AVIS
                        [name] => NYCC07
                        [line1] => 420 EAST 90TH STREET
                    )
                [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [companyName] => AVIS
                        [name] => NYCC06
                        [line1] => 310 EAST 64TH STREET
                    )
                [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [companyName] => AVIS
                        [name] => NYCC01
                        [line1] => 68 EAST 11TH STREET
                    )

            )

        [rates] => Array
            (
                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [pickupDropoffLocations] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [companyName] => AVIS
                                        [name] => NYCC07
                                    )
                            )
                        [vehicleRentalPrefType] => CCAR
                        [rateAmount] => 83.99
                        [rateCurrency] => USD
                    )
                [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [pickupDropoffLocations] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [companyName] => AVIS
                                        [name] => NYCC06
                                    )
                            )
                        [vehicleRentalPrefType] => CCAR
                        [rateAmount] => 110.54
                        [rateCurrency] => USD
                    )
                [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [pickupDropoffLocations] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [companyName] => AVIS
                                        [name] => NYCC01
                                    )
                            )
                        [vehicleRentalPrefType] => CCAR
                        [rateAmount] => 210.65
                        [rateCurrency] => USD
                    )

            )

    )
```

)

and this is the code:

```
$results_array = array();

foreach($result[0]->rates as $rate) {
    foreach($result[0]->companyLocationInfo as $info) {
        if($info->name == $rate->pickupDropoffLocations[0]->name) {
            $results_array[] = array(
                'line1' => $info->line1,
                'name' => $info->locationDetails->name,
                'companyName' => $info->companyName,
                'vehicleRentalPrefType' => $rate->vehicleRentalPrefType
            );
        }
    }
}
print_r($results_array);
```

Thank you.

Comment: what's this question got to do with XML or SOAP?

Comment: Because my code is with SimpleXML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do should be possible. If the code above is what you're actually trying to run, then your first problem is that you're comparing the values `"Joe"` and `"joe"` and those are not the same.

If you want a case-insensitive comparison, use `if (strcasecmp($var1, $var2) == 0)` (it returns zero if the two strings are the same, without considering case).